# Clone a general struct to a specific lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm playing around with the `cookie::Cookie` and would like to implement a simpler cookie jar for my own purpose.

```
pub struct NaiveCookieJar<'a> {
    data: HashMap<(String, String), Cookie<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> NaiveCookieJar<'a> {
    pub fn add<'b>(&mut self, domain: &str, name: &str, cookie: &'b Cookie<'b>) -> bool {
        let cookie: &'a Cookie = &cookie.clone();  // not working
        self.data
            .insert((String::from(domain), String::from(name)), *cookie)
            .is_some()
    }
}
```

This resulted in `error: E0495: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'c due to conflicting requirements`

What I want is for each of the arguments, they only need to live as long as the method itself, and I can make copies with `'a` lifetime to insert into the hash map. So if I've got something like

```
fn global_jar() -> &'static Mutex<NaiveCookieJar<'static>> {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref JAR: Mutex<NaiveCookieJar<'static>> = Mutex::new(NaiveCookieJar::new());
    }
    &JAR
}
```

...or in any cases that the cookie jar lives longer than the arguments, it won't trap me to instantiate structs with the corresponding lifetime.

There's a `Cookie::into_owned() -> Cookie<'static>` which fits this particular case but apparently I don't want the cookies to live longer than the jar if the jar isn't static itself.

FYI `Cookie` derives `Clone` but not `ToOwned`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

---

There is a fundamental misunderstanding here.

When `Cookie` is declared with a lifetime parameter, it means that it encapsulate a reference to an object with this lifetime.

In order to clone the `Cookie` for a longer lifetime, what you would have to do is to tease it apart, clone the referenced object for a longer lifetime, and then rebuild a brand new cookie referencing this new longer-lived object.

However, that is not what `clone` does by default<sup>1</sup>; `clone` simply passes on the *same* reference.

Therefore, the only change of lifetime you can get when cloning the `Cookie` is to *reduce* the lifetime, not extend it.

<sup>1</sup> *If you think about it, who would own the new object? Certainly not `Cookie`, it just has a reference!*

Comment: You were right. `Cookie` holds a `cookie_string: Option<Cow<'c, str>>`. But I deem such a smart pointer should be capable of copying the referenced data in an intelligent way? All members of `Cookie` are private, what is the proper way to do such a copy (rather than a bunch of set_xxx(get_xxx()))?

Comment: @FrederickZhang: You are stuck with the public API for the type (that's what an API is, after all); I would expect it has a constructor, so something like `Cookie::new(prev.get_xxx(), prev.get_yyy(), new_cookie_string, ...)`, if it doesn't you'll need to create a default cookie and use setters.

Comment: Sadly there isn't such an API. Actually I cannot have a direct access to `cookie_string` but only to `domain`, `name`, etc via provided APIs. However this would be effectively the same as `let cookie = Cookie::parse(cookie.to_string()).unwrap();`, which is ugly and inefficient.

Comment: @FrederickZhang: Then it might be time to file a bug against the library and discuss with the author what could be done to facilitate this task; and if it's open-source, you can also fork in the mean time.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your time